# how to upload recorded audio file to parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, avfoundation

Posted my code [here, was getting clipped below](http://pastebin.com/d8PM8u1B#).

As per the code above, I am creating an audio file called `sound.caf` at a known filepath location `soundfileURL`.

My question is how can I upload this file to Parse? How to get the file object in the code from the path `soundfileURL`.

My attempt below, needs work obviously. I haven't run it because i dont know how to convert `sound.caf` to PFFile and upload to Parse.

```
func addNamestoParse(obj: Music) {
    println("Doing Parse Stuff now")
    self.showActivityIndicatory(true)

    var className = PFObject(className: "musicrecording")
    className.setObject(obj.name, forKey: "nameofmusic")
    className.setObject(obj.createdOn, forKey: "datcreated")
```

**HOW TO CONVERT SOUND.CAF FILE TO PFFILE HERE & UPLOAD TO PARSE??**

```
    className.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if success == true {



        } else {

            println(error)

        }
    }

}
```

Thanks to **David Jirman** for the Objective-C equivalent was able to deduce the Swift Equivalent. Below is the code.

```
func addNamestoParse(obj: Name) {
    println("Doing Parse Stuff now")

    var className = PFObject(className: "namerecordings")
    className.setObject(obj.name, forKey: "babyname")
    className.setObject(obj.nameSubmitter, forKey: "submittedby")
    className.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if success == true {
            let audioFile = PFFile(name: "mysound.caf", data: NSData(contentsOfURL: self.soundFileURL)!)
            className["audioFile"] = audioFile

            className.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if success == false {
                    println("error in uploading audio file")
                } else {
                    println("posted successfully")

                }
            }

        } else {

            println(error)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @user1406716 - have you by any chance got the code to download audio files from Parse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754255/how-to-retrieve-audio-file-from-parse-swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After this great tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qj1piMAPE0 my solution was in Swift:

```
    let path = getCacheDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    var dataToUpload : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: filePath!)!

    let soundFile = PFFile(name: fileName, data: dataToUpload)
    var userSound = PFObject(className:"upload")
    userSound["name"] = "Sara"
    userSound["sound"] = soundFile
    userSound.saveInBackground()
```

where getCacheDirectory() is a function used in the tutorial

Answer (score 4):

I'm not well versed with Swift but in the "old way" the principle should be the same. You need to create a 'PFFile' and assign that to the appropriate PFFile attribute of your 'musicrecording' class. For example:

```
PFFile *pfFile = [PFFile fileWithData:data];
PFObject *pfObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"musicrecording"];
[pfObject setObject:pfFile forKey:@"musicFile"];
[pfObject saveInBackground];
```

When saving the object containing the PFFile object it uploads automatically. Does this help?

Comment: How to create the `data` to assign to `pfFile`. To create the `data`, I have a `filePath(NSURL)` only. does that help?

Comment: Well you said you have a known location `soundfileURL`, assuming it's of NSURL - the "old way" would be `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:soundfileURL];`

Comment: thank you that worked, I will post the swift code in the question and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Hi @DavidJirman do you by any chance know how to download audio files from Parse? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754255/how-to-retrieve-audio-file-from-parse-swift

Comment: @richc, here is a simple example of grabbing a PFFile from parse server:

        if let remoteAsset = pfObject[DataLibrary.tables.AssetTable.assetThumbnail] as? PFFile {
            remoteAsset.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData, error) in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                    cell?.assetThumbnail?.image = image
                }
            })
        }