# how to retrieve audio file from parse swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, avaudioplayer

I have successfully saved an Audio file to Parse but am struggling to download it again. I can't work out what the block should be to go with getDataInBackgroundWithBlock. And how to actually save the file. Any help much appreciated!

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "wordRecordings")
query.whereKey("wordName", equalTo: "\(joinedWord)")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil{                        
       for object in objects! {
            let audioFile = object["audioFile"] as! PFFile
            audioFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{ (audioFile: NSData, error:NSError?) -> Void in // THIS BLOCK ISNT CORRECT...
               if error == nil {
               let audioFile = AudioFile(data: audioFile) // THIS WORKS FOR IMAGES BUT NOT AUDIO - HOW DO I CREATE AN AUDIO FILE
               }
              }
             }
            } else {   
               print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
           }
         }
```

Thanks to @David below here is a working solution with path code as well.

```
let fileString = "\(fileName)"
let documentsDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let path = documentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileString)

audioFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (audioFile:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
         if error == nil {
           audioFile.writeToURL(path, atomically: true)
         } else {
         print("error with getData")
         }
  }
```

Comment: Depends on what do you want to do with the audio file - if you want, for example, play the audio you can directly instantiate your `AVAudioPlayer` either with the `NSData` (or even use `AVPlayer` with `PFFile`'s `url` and the  stream the data - be aware of the fact that AVAudioPlayer doesn't support remote streaming). If you want to save the audio file you can use `NSData`'s `writeToFile:atomically:`. Let me know if it helped or you need something else.

Comment: Hi David, thanks so much for looking at this. how would I write to file in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:) it should look something like this (I don't use Swift so please bear with me):

```
audioFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{ (audioFile: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let path = "path-to-your-file"
        if !audioFile.writeToFile(path, atomically: true){
            print("Error saving")
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend to go through some tutorials (e.g. [here](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/file-management-tutorial-ios8-swift)) where you might get better examples of file handling in Swift.

#### Update

Apparently both the block's parameters have to be optionals (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600588/parse-file-query-and-swift-1-2-error-getdatainbackgroundwithblock)). Your result block needs to be of type `(audioFile: NSData?, error: NSError?)`

Comment: hi - i tried the writeToURL based on that tutorial you suggested, but the PFDataResultBlock still isn't right. I have tried countless ideas, but am still stuck! Any ideas?

Comment: hm, apparently both the block's parameters have to be optionals (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29600588/2609269)). Try your result block to be of type `(audioFile: NSData?, error: NSError?)`. Works?

Comment: Indeed it does! I just found that too in the Parse documentation! I must have had my eyes closed all day! I have updated my question to include an answer. Thanks so much for your help!